# Is this a loophole in ecryptfs?

Tags: mount, encryption, ecryptfs

I have implemented below code to encrypt my drive.

Need a clarification regarding ecryptfs usage.

I have implemented below code in my script

---

```
   FILES_TO_BACKUP="/opt /opt/test /opt/test2 /opt/test3"
    KEY=1234
    time printf "%s" "${KEY}" | ecryptfs-add-passphrase --fnek - > tmp.txt
    cat tmp.txt

    #Now get the signature from the output of the above command
    SIG=`tail -1 tmp.txt | awk '{print $6}' | sed 's/\[//g' | sed 's/\]//g'`
    echo $SIG

    for i in $FILES_TO_BACKUP
    do
            PATH_TO_CRYPT=$i
            time mount -i -t ecryptfs $PATH_TO_CRYPT $PATH_TO_CRYPT \
                  -o noauto,ecryptfs_passthrough,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_sig=$SIG,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=$SIG,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs
done
```

---

From above code, I am adding key to the kernel key ring. From there on, I am using the SIG (authentication token) to mount the folder as encrypted folders. Note I am not using $KEY anymore.

After running my script, if I execute $mount command, I see

```
--- 
/opt/test on /opt/test type ecryptfs (rw,relatime,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=3208187a52bf0f9c,ecryptfs_sig=3208187a52bf0f9c,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_passthrough,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs)
---
```

Where the authentication token 3208187a52bf0f9c is displayed. Is this secure ? If somebody types mount command when my devivce is on and later try to use this same ID to mount my hard drive partition by connecting to another PC, will they be able to hack my hard drive ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They would have to be able to reverse a SHA512 hash in order to make use of the key signature. That isn't currently possible so you should be fine.

I hope the script, containing the key, will not be stored on the same device that you're using eCryptfs on. If an attacker gains possession of that script, they will have everything they need to decrypt your files.

Comment: Sorry tyhicks, I didnt get you. Mount command (if he notes down when I am away by typing mouth command) is displaying the signature  value 3208187a52bf0f9c. He can use this to mount the directory right? Just thinking of worst case scenario

Comment: I figured out that if the authentication token is available in kernel ring buffer, the hacker can mount the ecryptfs directory with the SIG value. So, its always better to clear the kernel key ring buffer right after mounting ecryptfs folders. Using keyctl I cleared the keyring buffer and hacker cant mount using SIG.